# Can I Import or open SQLite file (.db) to android project?

Tags: android, sqlite

Can I Import or open exiting SQLite file (.db) to android project ??

I already have the .db file with a tons of records (~80,000 records)

what is the best way to deal whit that? how? can any one guide me please!

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking "how do I ship this existing SQLite database with my app, to use as a starter database for users?", [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper):

First, put your database in `assets/databases/` in your project (e.g., `assets/databases/constants.db`)

Next, save a tiny subclass of `SQLiteAssetHelper` that supplies the name of the database:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2008-2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
*/

package com.commonsware.android.dbasset;

import android.content.Context;
import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME="constants.db";

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
  }
}
```

Finally, use the `SQLiteAssetHelper` subclass as you would use a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to get at your database

(above code from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets))